# How to recover Azure DevOps credentials

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, vscode-extensions

I wrote and published a VSCode extension. I forgot the credentials I used for setting up the publisher.
I have the publisher name (visible on the extension homepage in the marketplace), an expired PAT (created with `vcse login`), and the email where info about the extension is sent.
How can I generate a new PAT to update the extension?

Comment: May I please ask where did you find the email? I'm facing the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way available with Microsoft for doing that. You can go ahead and raise a support ticket with Microsoft to request this feature.

Answer (score 0):

> How to recover Azure DevOps credentials

Since you have the email where info about the extension is sent, the email count should be the count of the Azure DevOps credentials.

Then you can select the option Forgot my password to reset the password, verify the security code by email or Phone:

[image]

[image]

After reset the password, you can reset or create a new PAT to update the extension.